# CSS Box shadow doesn't appear in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been trying this but for some strange reason, The box-shadow won't appear for the `<nav>` tag. I also tried changing the z-index to a higher value incase the next element was above it, still it doesn't work. Can anyone help with this and a possible explanation?

Here's the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/dqLvaghn/2/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `box-shadow` 4th value is too big. But before that issue, add `position:relative` to your both elements, because `z-index` doesn't work without a `position` value.

Comment: Yep ! adding `position:relative;` fixed the problem.

Comment: mine was crazy weird, no set of position set, worked on white background but not with color; Fix was set z-index to I'm guessing anything greater than 1, my guess is it has something to do with display flex.